# A problem about polynomial function composition

Tags: functions, polynomials, contest-math

I have a problem about polynomial function composition that I am trying to solve, if possible, I would like some help or advice.

Let $f_1(x) = x^2 + 4x + 2$, and for $n\geq2, f_n(x)$ be the $nth$ composition of $f_1(x)$, e.g:

$f_2(x) = x^4 + 8x^3 + 24x^2 + 32x + 14$.

And now, let $S_n$ be the sum of the coefficients of the terms of even degree of $f_n(x)$, e.g, $S_2 = 1+24+14 = 39$. Find $S_{2022}$.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?

Comment: The answer is going to be a **really** big number.  What are you going to do with it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't have any ideas to solve it... the question came up in a university competition I entered, and I couldn't think of anything good enough....

Comment: The number is $\frac{3^{2^{2020}}-3}{2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sketch (you must complete the details). If $f(x)$ is any polynomial then the sum of the coefficients of the terms of even degree of $f(x)$ is
$$
\frac{f(1)+f(-1)}{2}
$$
(why?). So in this case we have
$$
S_n = \frac{f_n(1)+f_n(-1)}{2}.
$$
Write $a_n=f_n(1)$ and $b_n=f_n(-1)$. Note that $a_1=7=3^2-2$ and that we have the recurrence relation
$$
a_{n+1} = a_n^2 + 4a_n + 2.
$$
An exploration of the first terms of this sequence gives
$$
a_2 = 79 = 3^{4}-2 = 3^{2^2}-2, \quad a_3 = 6559 = 3^8-2 = 3^{2^3}-2,
$$
so we conjecture that $a_n = 3^{2^n}-2$. You can prove this by induction on $n$.

On the other hand, you can easily verify that $b_n=-1$ for all $n$. Thus
$$
S_n = \frac{3^{2^n}-2-1}{2} = \frac{3^{2^n}-3}{2}.
$$

Comment: Oh, yes hahaha. Thank you so much. Nice idea.